# Scheduled Background task for daily at specific time in iOS

Tags: ios

I need some help for scheduling a Background task at daily basis at specific time in iOS.
I want to call a webservice at a specific time (let's say at 1.00 am ) and download all new data to app.
After searching a lot, I came to know about Notifications and timer to do such things but I have some questions

1. Suppose I create scheduled job on server which sends a push notification at 1 am to device.
   After receiving push notification can my app start automatically (without any user interaction with app icon or push notification)?
   What should be happen when at 1 am the device has not an active internet connection or my app does not receive the push notification?
2. Suppose I create a Timer or a local notification to schedule the download at 1 am - it will call the web service only if my app is running

How do I achieve this?
Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: You might consider using "Background Fetch", discussed in [Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56) in _App Programming Guide for iOS: Background Execution._ You don't control when the call is made, but is designed explicitly for the scenario of periodically updating the app's data even when the app is not running.

Comment: Yes I have gone throughout that option also but my downloading data is large might be it takes 15 min or more than that , "Background Fetch" will fetch data around 30 sec only. Also for periodically updating you will not  have control that when to update app data,it will update on basis of  uses(frequency) of app...So I don't think this option will work..If any correction over statement please correct me.

Comment: In WWDC 2013 video, [What's New with Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=204), Apple suggests that one should marry background fetch (to quickly check to see if there is data to download) with background `NSURLSession` (to initiate a larger download). BTW, that video walks through both this opportunistic fetch model and remote notification approach.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question

> 1- After receiving push notification app will not start automatically until user will himself click on that push notification.
>
> If device will have no internet access then again your notification will not be transferred.

I recommend you that you should go with push notification.you can Schedule
your push notification and when it receives on user device run a webService for successfully receiving of notification which will tell that notification successfully delivered in case if it will not be delivered due to internet problem or something else then you can again schedule notification after 30 minutes again until you will get a success.

there is no other option for achieving this.

Comment: Do you mean ,to schedule notification in iOS app and not on server side? but  can  i scheduled push notification ?(i think we can only scheduled local notifications)...Also u said app only wake up if user run it ..but i need to download all data to device even if app is not launched or  not being used by user or in background mode..so is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I mean Push notification which will be triggered from server and after successful delivery you can trigger a webservice that you have received the notification.

Comment: so u say when push notification receives in didReceiveRemoteNotification method call web service to download data ...but again If app is in background  or not running then also this didReceiveRemoteNotification method gets called? and what will happen if downloading takes more time may be 15 min?